# Inserting photo and get photo

Tags: php

Hi i want to make it possible when user sign up default photo upload in my DB right now i'm upload it but i don't know if its correct or not here its the code:

```
 <?php
 require_once 'includes/header.php';

  $profile_pic = basename('files/img/default.jpg');

 if (Input::exists()) {
 //also here we check our token to see if input
if (Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {
//new instance
$validate = new Validate();
//now here we check our validation with check method
//fist of all we check if its POST then:
$validation = $validate->check($_POST,array(
//contain all rulles we want

//first of all in username as we set in our DB
'username'  => array(
  //its required
   'required' => true,
   //minimum character 2
   'min'      => 2,
   //maximum character 20
   'max'      => 20,
   //and we want it unique on users table
   'unique'   => 'users'
),
'name'      => array(
  'required' => true,
  //minimum character 2
  'min'      => 2,
  //maximum character 20
  'max'      => 50,
),
'email'      => array(
  'required' => true,
  //minimum character 2
  'min'      => 10,
  //maximum character 20
  'max'      => 50,
),
'password' => array(
  'required' => true,
  //minimum character 2
  'min'      => 6,
),
'SecondPassword' => array(
  'required' => true,
  //check for be match with password1
  'matches'  => 'password'
 ),


  ));
 //is passed
if($validation->passed()){
  $user = new User();
  $salt = Hash::salt(32);

  try {
    $user->create(array(
      'username' => Input::get('username') ,
      'name' => Input::get('name') ,
      'email' => Input::get('email') ,
      'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'),$salt) ,
      'salt' => $salt,
      'joined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s') ,
      'lastlogin' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
      'avatar' => $profile_pic

    ));
    Session::flash('home','<span class="success-sign">Thank you for your      
     regsiteration Please log in</span> ');
    Redirect::to('index.php');

  } catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
  }

  }else {
  //if error
  foreach ($validation->errors() as $error) {
    echo "<span class='error-sign'>$error</span><br>";
          }
      }
    } 
  }
    ?>

 <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <label for="username" class='field-name'>Username</label><br>
<!--here in value we declare it to use get method from Input class to get
username for when we see error we dont miss this value and also for name -->
 <input type="text" name="username" id="username"
     value="<?php echo Input::get('username');?>" autocomplete="off"
      onBlur ='checkUser(this)' class='signup'>
     <span id='info'></span>
<br>

  <label for="name" class='field-name'>Your name</label><br>
  <input type="text" name="name"
     value="<?php echo Input::get('name');?>" id="name" class='signup' >
 <br>

<label for="email" class='field-name'>Your Email</label><br>
<input type='email' name='email' id="email" value="<?php echo    
Input::get('email'); ?>"
class='signup'><br>


  <label for="password1" class='field-name'>Password</label><br>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class='signup'>
  <br>

  <label for="secondpassword" class='field-name-re'>Retype Password</label> 
   <br>
  <input type="password" name="SecondPassword" id="SecondPassword"         
  class='signup'> 
  <br>

 <!--this is for token value-->
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate();?>">
<br>
<span class='fieldname'>&nbsp;</span>
<input type="submit" value="SignUp" class='info-signup'>
</form>
<br>
```

now as i said i see that in my DB the default.jpg is exists when user sign up but first i don't know if its photo or just name of photo and second i cant show this photo in user profile page

Answer (score 0):

You Never want to actually save an Image's actual data into the database.
With that being said, your code stores the Path name into the database like how it should have been done.

Double check if you are using the correct path.

use

```
<img src="<?php echo $your_avatar_url; ?> />
```

to output your image.

look into How to have user upload the image here
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually save POSTed photo. Check out [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.move-uploaded-file.php) function.